# Why submit transaction every row is so slow?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

The table is empty at first .
 **when i commit the transaction  after  20000 row ,it cost less than 1 second .**
[image]

```
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ipTable (ip) VALUES (?)");
  $stmt->bind_param("i", $ip);
  $conn->query('BEGIN');
  for( $count = 0  ; $count < 20000 ; $count ++){
  $ip = rand(1,10000000);
  $stmt->execute();
  }
  $conn->query('COMMIT');
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
```

**with time  command**

```
time php test.php



real    0m0.785s
user    0m0.220s
sys     0m0.096s
```

But when I  commented out  the   **$conn->query('BEGIN');  $conn->query('COMMIT');**
, it run more than 20 minute and don't know how much time i have to wait to finish .I have to stop it with ctrl-c .

```
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ipTable (ip) VALUES (?)");
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $ip);
       //$conn->query('BEGIN');
      for( $count = 0  ; $count < 20000 ; $count ++){
      $ip = rand(1,10000000);
      $stmt->execute();
      }
      //$conn->query('COMMIT');
      $stmt->close();
      $conn->close();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning on autocommit

`$conn->autocommit(TRUE);`

```
$conn->autocommit(TRUE);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ipTable (ip) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $ip);
//$conn->query('BEGIN');
for( $count = 0  ; $count < 20000 ; $count ++){
    $ip = rand(1,10000000);
    $stmt->execute();
}
//$conn->query('COMMIT');
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: why without   $conn->autocommit(TRUE);  it run slow?

Comment: I think u have autocommit set to false somewhere. So it wasn't working because when set to false you have to tell it when to begin transaction and when to finish (commit). Now that autocommit is true. Everytime it execute it will make the changes to the db.

Comment: I dont think it runs slow it just doesn't actually make changes to your db until you commit.

Comment: i  don't  set  auto_commit   false. i  just  write a  demo  to  test   how  much  time to  insert  20000 row，maybe  it  is  default  false.